# MVC Antiforgery requestvalidation token appearing in querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, antiforgerytoken

I have an MVC 3 view with the following code:-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Order.SearchResults(), FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.Button("btnSearch", "Search", HtmlButtonType.Submit, null, new { @class = "button primary icon search", alt = "Search the orders (up to 50 characters)" }
}
```

When I post the form I see the __RequestVerificationToken= and the contents of the verifcation token within the querystring.

Any ideas why this may be the case and how to sort it?

Answer (score 4):

Anti forgery token work only with POST requests. If you want to use them you need to change the verb used of the form to POST instead of GET:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Order.SearchResults(), FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.Button("btnSearch", "Search", HtmlButtonType.Submit, null, new { @class = "button primary icon search", alt = "Search the orders (up to 50 characters)" }
}
```

Comment: Correct - Thanks it was using a Post and I changed it a while back and hadnt realised that this would cause my issue.

Comment: @gsuttie, are there still some issues or maybe you could consider closing this question by [marking the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround how you can pass antiforegy value through GET method or even in headers. More details [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/10/preventing-csrf-with-ajax.aspx).