# RequestVerificationToken in query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, query-string

I have an issue with ajax posts I'm doing for a form that contains @Html.AntiForgeryToken().

When I post the form via ajax I get the following query string:
http://myhost.local/Assessment/NextQuestion/15?__RequestVerificationToken=HVHkyjrwWupa9pU6tiMVjSDept5XeBtCyNL0tHwWEkfFDHJLXps9oRG7AlfvVHOx0tK0pE78KaQMD7gL5YBBXu_TfKhC3Pd69WaGCldFhPQhbP2t0

How do I remove this from the query string? The query string doesn't contain this when doing a standard post.

Form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("NextQuestion", "Assessment", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-vertical"}))
    {

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        ....
    }
```

Post function:

```
$('form.ajaxForm').on('submit', (function() {
        $("#loadingIndicator").show();
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: $('form.ajaxForm').attr("action"),
                data: $('form.ajaxForm').serialize(),
                success:
                    function(result) {
                        $("#loadingIndicator").hide();
                        if (result.redirect) {
                            window.location.href = result.redirect;
                            return;
                        } else {
                            alert(result.ValidationMessage());
                        }
                    },
                error:
                    function(req, status, err) {
                        alert('error');
                        $("#loadingIndicator").hide();
                    },
            });
        return false;
    }));
```

Action Method:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public JsonResult NextQuestion(AssessmentModel model)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is being added to the query string as it is a mandatory requirement when using

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

and

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

The AntiForgeryToken must be returned to the server so that it can be validated appropriately, and because you are doing

```
data: $('form.ajaxForm').serialize(),
```

and the AntiForgeryToken is in your form, it is serialized appropriately.

Therefore it is a necessary requirement if you are to use the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken].

If i've missed something, and all you want to do is to remove it from the query string for some other reason, then you would need to somehow string process the output of your call to

```
$('form.ajaxForm').serialize()
```

I'd suggest using a regular expression of some sort to search for __RequestVerificationToken and either end of string, or until the next &/start of next querystring key value pair.

Comment: Ok - my mistake - not sure why, but I'd assumed you were doing a Get, as discussed here...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473917/mvc-antiforgery-requestvalidation-token-appearing-in-querystring